# How to Calculate Memory Used By A Command?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, command

Consider I am running a command :

```
cprogram.c using gcc command
```

Memory used by following command:

```
gcc cprogram.c
```

Note :
top and ps commands are not supposed to be used.

I need other way to calculate memory used by command and this memory should be specific to this command only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `/usr/bin/time` to get the peak memory used by a command:

```
/usr/bin/time -l ps
```

**Output**

```
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
97160 ttys000    0:00.01 -bash
97167 ttys000    0:00.00 /usr/bin/time -l ps
        0.00 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys
    946176  maximum resident set size                     <-- peak memory usage
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
       244  page reclaims
         0  page faults
         0  swaps
         3  block input operations
         0  block output operations
         0  messages sent
         0  messages received
         0  signals received
         5  voluntary context switches
         0  involuntary context switches
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, you can go straight to the source `ps` uses: information about memory usage (among other things) is exposed on the `/proc` filesystem. For example, try `cat /proc/1234/status` as root, where 1234 is the pid of the process.

Note that this would likely not count memory used by gcc's subprocesses.

Comment: I will try this option but is there any other way we can display command's memory info without using pid and ps/top commands ?